# Fetching repeated data from database without repetition

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Guys I have a table in database like this.
[open to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcsku.jpg)

I need to fetch data such that i have only variety and number of grafts each date summed up without repetition.

I get this instead: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmydF.png)

Comment: Your result provided data that not match the table. Please ask more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is the query you are looking for

```
select sum(variety), sum(number_grafts), date 
from <table_name> 
group by date
```

Comment: Hi, This query sums all the varieties and all number of grafts.
I need one that now sums for each variety and results in each variety and number of grafts for that variety.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would give you aggregate of sum of the no of grafts for a variety on a given date `select variety, sum(number_grafts), date 
from <table_name> 
group by date, variety` I believe that's what you mean.